# Use VBO in Drupal through ajax action

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have written a user action for bulk approving user

I want to implement it using page refresh.Right now the pags is getting refresh

I want to implement using ajax .

How can i go about it

In the view i have selected Use AJAX:Yes but still the page is refreshing

```
function bulkapprove_action_info() {
  $actions = array( 
    'bulkapprove_user_approve_action' => array(
      'type' => 'user', // Can be file, term, user, etc.
      'label' => t('Approve User'),
      'configurable' => FALSE, // Doesn't need config form
      'behavior' => array('changes_property'), // Uses view access rights  ,
      'pass rows' => TRUE,
       'vbo_configurable' => FALSE,
      'triggers' => array('any'), // Works always
    )

  return $actions;

function bulkapprove_user_approve_action(&$entity, $context) 
{


   $entity->field_user_status['und'][0]['value'] = 'Approved';
   //drupal_set_message(t('Users are  approved '), 'status');


}
```

Comment: Any inputs please ....

Answer (score 1):

I think you have created a Page View , so entire the page is a view, option "Use Ajax" doesn't work for this format and will reload the page.

You need to create a Block View and include it in a page for using ajax with it.